# How to use `expect` with `zipcloak`?

Tags: zip, expect

I create a `zip` file using `zip` which includes several files and directories, named `test.upd`. Now I want to use `expect` to automatically handle the password encryption. Here are two bash scripts, both do not work:

```
!/bin/bash

MYPWD="mypassword"

expect -c '
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect {
       "*Enter password*" { send "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
                                   exp_continue
                                  }
       "*Verify password*" { send "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
                                      exp_continue
                                    }
    }'
```

and this file:

```
!/bin/bash
MYPWD="mypassword"

expect -c '
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect "*Enter password*" 
    send "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
    expect "*Verify password*" 
    send "'"$MYPWD"'\r"

    }'
```

I also tried to create an `expect` script directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn zipcloak test.upd
expect "*Enter password*" 
send "password\r"
expect "*Verify password*" 
send "password\r"
```

All scripts seem to send correctly the first password request, but it looks like the text for the second password entry is never asked. How can I do it right?

Constraints:

- I have to use `zipcloak` (NOT `zip`)
- I want to use `expect` to automatically set the password.

Remarks:

- I have used the correct script
- Each time, when using the first script, an empty file starting with `zi` is created in the directory, like `ziSvbYhy` or `zi3gzEQ4`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution seem to be to wait some time before actions! I have absolutely no idea why this is (comments, explanations and insights welcome), but the following script works now for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYPWD="mypassword"

expect -c ' 
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect "*Enter password*" 
    sleep 1
    send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
    sleep 1
    expect "*Verify password*" 
    sleep 1
    send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
    sleep 1
    '
```

Comment: Do you need the two `sleep`s after the `send`s?

Comment: Yes, I need to two `sleep`s after the two `send`. Otherwise the zipfile is not encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

It is my interpretation that the answers from Alex and ctrl-alt-delor don't properly wait for the zipcloak process to finish and therefore are prone to leave the zip file unencrypted (and leave a temporary file with a name such as `zimfwtpJ` behind). So their code work for small zip files but fail for larger ones.

Here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYPWD="mypassword"

expect -c '
    set timeout -1
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect "*Enter password*"
    send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
    expect "*Verify password*"
    send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
    expect eof
    '
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example in the question worked for me.

```
!/bin/bash
MYPWD="mypassword"

expect -c '
     spawn zipcloak test.upd
     expect {
        "*Enter password*" { send "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
                               exp_continue
                              }
        "*Verify password*" { send "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
                                  exp_continue
                                }
}'
```

Though the second did not. Try it again, maybe you where running the wrong script. That often happens to me: I wonder why it does not work, but I am running the wrong script.

Comment: Nope, this script does NOT work for me. The zipped files is NOT encrypted after the procedure. Maybe there is a difference in the version of `zipcloak` or `expect`, or some libraries are differrent? I have double- and triple checked to run the script EXACTLY as it is! Also, each time a file like `ziSvbYhy` is created in the directory (different names).

Comment: Did you try to run `zipcloak` manually?

Comment: Yes, of cource I used `zipcloak` manually; also to see how to use it.