# How to use `expect` with `zipcloak` II?

Tags: ubuntu, expect

This question is a followup on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102559/how-to-use-expect-with-zipcloak), as I figured out the solution I presented in the previous question does not work anymore. It worked sometime, but now `expect` does not work as expected. Here is the full code again:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYPWD="mypassword"

expect -c ' 
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect "*Enter password*" 
    sleep 1
    send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
    sleep 1
    expect "*Verify password*" 
    sleep 1
    send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
    sleep 1
    '
```

This bash script does not encrypt the file `test.upd`, but creates files in my directory starting with "zi", like `zi0gA1rU` or `zi8Vv6OD`.

Why is that? What are those files? Why does the above script sometimes work, and sometimes it does not? Is there no way to make `expect` to behave as it should?

Where can I find the source code of `zipcloak`, so I can rewrite it to avoid using `expect`?

Additional information:

- I have to execute this command as `root`, as the zipfile has root rights. Maybe that is important?

  zipcloak -v
  Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zipcloak "-L"' for software license.

  This is ZipCloak 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
  Currently maintained by E. Gordon.  Please send bug reports to
  the authors using the web page at www.info-zip.org; see README for details.

  Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip,
  as of above date; see http://www.info-zip.org/ for other sites.

  Compiled with gcc 4.6.1 for Unix (Linux ELF) on Jun 11 2011.

  ZipCloak special compilation options:
      [encryption, version 2.91 of 05 Jan 2007]

After it stopped working, I needed to set the last `sleep` to 2. Then it worked again. But later, this also did not work anymore. So I set the `sleep` to 5 seconds. For now, my script is working. But NOT reliable.

Debug output with `exp_internal 1` set:

```
spawn /usr/bin/test.upd
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {28746}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*Enter password*"? no
Enter password: 
expect: does "Enter password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*Enter password*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Enter password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Enter password: "
send: sending "XXX\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*Verify password*"? no

Verify password: 
expect: does "\r\nVerify password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*Verify password*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\r\nVerify password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nVerify password: "
send: sending "XXX\r" to { exp6 }
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -c  argv[2] = 
    exp_internal 1
    spawn /usr/bin/zipcloak "test.upd"
    expect "*Enter password*"
    sleep 1
    send  "XXX\r"
    sleep 1
    expect "*Verify password*"
    sleep 1
    send  "XXX\r"
    sleep 1

set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
```

**Update:** The output of the second script posted by glenn is:

```
spawn zipcloak test.upd
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {9956}
Gate keeper glob pattern for 'password: $' is 'password: '. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
Enter password:
expect: does "Enter password: " (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Enter password: "
send: sending "mypassword\r" to { exp6 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
mypassword

expect: does "mypassword\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
expect: timed out
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -c  argv[2] =
    exp_internal 1
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect {
        -re {password: $} {send "mypassword\r"; exp_continue}
        eof
    }

set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
```

**Update**

I actually want to specify the filename and the password on the commandline to call the code as

```
./myscript.sh test.upd pass
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c " 
    exp_internal 1
    spawn zipcloak \"$1\"
    expect {
        -re {password: \$} {send \"$2\r\"; exp_continue}
        expect eof
    }
"
```

However, it creates again a file starting with `zi` and does not encrypt the actual file. I had no idea that every little seemingly logic change could break the entire workflow of the expect script. Here is the ouput:

```
spawn zipcloak test.upd
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {16791}
Gate keeper glob pattern for 'password: $' is 'password: '. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
"expect"? no
Enter password:
expect: does "Enter password: " (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Enter password: "
send: sending "pass\r" to { exp6 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
"expect"? no
pass

expect: does "pass\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
"expect"? no
expect: timed out
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -c  argv[2] =
    exp_internal 1
    spawn zipcloak "test.upd"
    expect {
        -re {password: $} {send "pass\r"; exp_continue}
        expect eof
    }

set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
```

Comment: I just increased the sleep time to '2' and now it seems to work. But why is that? Does the sleep time depend on how long I have this crap installed on my system? Does it depend on the daytime? On the comets that fell into the sun...? This is the most confusing problem I ever encountered... Should I use a value of 1000 just to be sure?

Comment: If you have correct expect patterns you should not have to sleep at all. While you're developing, add `exp_internal 1` command somewhere before the spawn command.

Comment: @Alex, you have to wait for `zipcloak` to finish which `expect eof` as in glen's solution or `wait` (or ideally both) should take care of.

Comment: I have replaced `sleep 1` with `eof` which gave an error. `wrong # args: should be "eof channelId"
    while executing
"eof"`

Comment: `eof` is a pattern, so you want `expect eof`

Answer (score 4):

I'd write that zipcloak-er as

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set zipfile [lindex $argv 0]
if {![file exists $zipfile]} {error "no such zipfile: $zipfile"}
set pass "mypassword"
spawn zipcloak $zipfile
expect {
    -re {password: $} {send "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
    eof
}
```

Since the "enter password: " and "verify password: " prompts have a common suffix, it makes sense to use `exp_continue` to reuse the code.

---

"does not work" is not helpful. Did you use `exp_internal 1`? Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYPWD="mypassword"

expect -c " 
    exp_internal 1
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect {
        -re {password: \$} {send \"$MYPWD\\r\"; exp_continue}
        eof
    }
"
```

---

Sorry Alex, I don't understand your issue. This is what happens for me in bash:

```
$ zip test.upd file
  adding: file (deflated 22%)
$ MYPWD="mypassword"
$ expect -c " 
    exp_internal 1
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect {
        -re {password: \$} {send \"$MYPWD\\r\"; exp_continue}
        eof
    }
"
```

```
spawn zipcloak test.upd
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {27485}
Gate keeper glob pattern for 'password: $' is 'password: '. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
Enter password: 
expect: does "Enter password: " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Enter password: "
send: sending "mypassword\r" to { exp4 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no

Verify password: 
expect: does "\r\nVerify password: " (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nVerify password: "
send: sending "mypassword\r" to { exp4 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no


expect: does "\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
encrypting: file

expect: does "\r\nencrypting: file\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match regular expression "password: $"? Gate "password: "? gate=no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\nencrypting: file\r\n"
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -c  argv[2] =  
    exp_internal 1
    spawn zipcloak test.upd
    expect {
        -re {password: $} {send "mypassword\r"; exp_continue}
        eof
    }

set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
```

Comment: I am afraid your suggestion does not seem work. After about 10 seconds `zipinfo` shows the file in question is not encrypted, while an empty file is created in the same directory starting with the phrase 'zi' (like `zi8H9A9b` or `ziwlvWI3`).

Comment: Again, the above suggestion does not work for me.

Comment: @Alex, and what's the output of glenn's script?

Comment: I have included the output in my question

Comment: Please see updated question...

Comment: I don't know what's up with your zipcloak. You never get to see the verify password prompt, where I do. ... brain wave: what's the password you're using? Does it have special characters like backslash or quotes?

Comment: No special characters, not even numbers. Just small and capital characters.